# Porque no se visualiza mi pdf?

Tags: php, pdf

en mi caso lo que quiero es mostrar un PDF lo que paasa es que cuando lo quiero visualizar, a veces si a veces no, me devuelve este mensaje:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi codigo seria el siguiente:

```
 <?php

$ruta = $_GET["ruta"];
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=documento.pdf");
#comprobamos si existe el archivo
if (file_exists($ruta)) {
    #si existe lo mostramos
    readfile("D:/$ruta");
    echo $ruta;
    echo "Existe";
} else {
    #si no existe mostramos un error
    echo "No existe el archivo";
}
?>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Subir archivo</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!--vamos a visualizar un pdf de la variable $ETIQUET -->
    <?php
    $path = $_POST['ruta'];
    ?>
    <embed src=" https://web/calendario/pdf.php?ruta=<?php echo $path; ?>"
        type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
    <!--boton para imprimir el pdf-->
    <button onclick="window.print()">Imprimir</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Lo dicho a veces si me mustra a veces no me muestra el pdf, algo me hace pensar que el nombre del pdf tiene espacios, el simbolo mas(+),y accentos, la cosa es que no puedo cambiar  el nombre ni su forma de crearlo.

Comment: Espero que estes al tanto de que se puede leer el contenido de CUALQUIER archivo del sistema con tan solo modificar el valor de la variable ruta que para colmo se pasa por GET.

Comment: @Marcos lo se, tan solo quería hacer unas pruebas, esta aplicación no se hará publica, gracias por avisar igualmente

Answer (score 1):

Estuve revisando tu script y funciona sin problemas tal vez tu problema se genera al hacer el llamado a tu script, recuerda que si lo estas haciendo a través de `GET` debes hacer el llamado junto con los parámetros, o sea:

```
 script.php?ruta=\Directorio\archivo.pdf
```

También puedes poner el encabezado del archivo al final del script, para poder hacer la depuración de este y así mediante una orden `exit();` ver donde se esta produciendo el problema.

```php
<?php
$ruta = $_GET["ruta"];
#comprobamos si existe el archivo
if (file_exists($ruta)) {
    #si existe lo mostramos
    readfile("D:/$ruta");
    echo $ruta;
    echo "Existe";
} else {
    #si no existe mostramos un error
    echo "No existe el archivo";
}

exit(); // Ponlo aquí para ver que la ruta pasa bien.

header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=file.pdf");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto es lo que me ha funcionado a mi:
Como verán e creado 2 divs ver-libro y ver-libro-movil, el primero lo veo en las pc y pantallas grandes y luego lo desactivo con un display:none; y hago que se vea el móvil y con ese código no e tenido problemas. es importante agregar a la cabecera el enlace de script

```html
<div class="ver-libro">
        <embed id="fraDisabled" src="dkk6g46h7bvb77744pi4hfhaqw913g/libros/libros-pdf/<?php echo htmlspecialchars($libroPdf); ?>#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" type="application/pdf" loading="lazy" width="100%" height="800px" onload="disableContextMenu();" onMyLoad="disableContextMenu();"/>
      </div>
      <!--celular-->
    <div class="ver-libro-movil">
    <iframe src="https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=https://clubdr.online/dkk6g46h7bvb77744pi4hfhaqw913g/libros/libros-pdf/<?php echo htmlspecialchars($libroPdf); ?>" width="100%" height="1000px"></iframe>
        </div>
```

```html
<div class="ver-libro">
        <embed id="fraDisabled" src="dkk6g46h7bvb77744pi4hfhaqw913g/libros/libros-pdf/<?php echo htmlspecialchars($libroPdf); ?>#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" type="application/pdf" loading="lazy" width="100%" height="800px" onload="disableContextMenu();" onMyLoad="disableContextMenu();"/>
      </div>
      <!--celular-->
    <div class="ver-libro-movil">
    <iframe src="https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=https://clubdr.online/dkk6g46h7bvb77744pi4hfhaqw913g/libros/libros-pdf/<?php echo htmlspecialchars($libroPdf); ?>" width="100%" height="1000px"></iframe>
        </div>
```

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="chrome/browser/resources/pdf/pdf_viewer.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<embed src=" https://web/calendario/pdf.php?ruta=<?php echo $path; ?>"
```

Acá tenes un espacio... yo lo tengo así y me funciona perfectamente para web, pero no para android...

```
<embed src="dkk6g46h7bvb77744pi4hfhaqw913g/libros/libros-pdf/<?php echo htmlspecialchars($libroPdf); ?>" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="750px"/>
```

Comment: Esto no es una respuesta; el problema es que el sitio no es un foro ... y si la gente ven respuesta como esta llega la maldicion del dedo facil y te mete un voto negativo... este tipo de cosas es mejor meterlas en una actualizacion de tu post ... o comentarios...